# Ember Cannot read property 'createRecord' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I getting the following error when I tries to return model from the route

[image]

My model task.js

```
 //My Code for returning the model
      //My Model initialization :
        Taskmanagementfortenmiles.Task = DS.Model.extend({
          display_id: DS.attr('string'),
          type: DS.attr('string'),
          display_name: DS.attr('string'),
          isCompleted:DS.attr('boolean'),
          timestamp: DS.attr() 
        });
```

My Route task_route.js:

```
Taskmanagementfortenmiles.TaskRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

    model: function() {
     return $.getJSON("http://localhost:3000/tasks").then(function(response) {
                  var task = [];
                  var self = this;
                  response.forEach(function(task) {
                   console.log(self.store.createRecord('task', {
                        display_id: random_id,
                        type: type,
                        display_name: displayName,
                        isCompleted: false,
                        timestamp: date
                    }).save());
                }); 
                return task;
              });
  },
});
```

Is my version of ember data is my problem for getting the error?

Please somebody help me in this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried putting the self=this before the return statement?

Comment: @Fred john Thanks for the quick reply. I tried to declare outside. Its works  fine.:-). But it now returning "Uncaught Error: No model was found for 'task'". But I have the model Taskmanagementfortenmiles.Task in task.js

Comment: You are not using ember-cli, correct?

Comment: @locks I am Using yoeman ember generator. And grunt server.

Comment: `var self = this;` needs to be after the line `model: function` in your case this/self is the query context not the routes context.

+ you defined a var `task` as an array and habe a task parameter in your function as well. return task will be empty with this implementation.